# Ubuntu MonoDevelop can't start without errors

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I worked on ubuntu 14.04 and MonoDevelop 5.10. But it can't start after I upgraded mono to 4.2.1. Now MonoDevelop start without no errors but can't see anything. Can any one help me ? Thanks.

After added MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug, I find it stop on this line:

```
Mono: DllImport searching in: '/usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('/usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_TMP_MAX'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_TMP_MAX'.
```

Mono didn't find anything, and wait here.

Comment: Have you check system log files or mono log files? Surely some error is logged somewhere!

Comment: I didn't see any log files, but after added MONO_LOG_LEVEL variable, I have find the reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by install monodevelop-opt, and it didn't use system libmono.

Thanks for opensuse!

link: http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=home:tpokorra:mono&package=monodevelop-opt